# How to visualize the value of a pointer while debugging in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

So, I have a variable buffPtr: TPointer
It has a size of 16 and contains a series of numbers, mostly starting with 0, say something like 013854351387365.
I'm sure it contains values, because the application does what it does fine.

I want to see this value while I'm debugging.

If I add "PAnsiChar(buffPtr)^" to the watches I only see the first byte.

Comment: Did you tried to put PAnsiChar(BufPtr) (without the ^)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I added a watch to 
PAnsiChar(buffPtr)^

with the Watch Properties as

Repeat Count = 16
Decimal

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question or the answer. Could you elaborate?

Comment: It would be nice if you also included a picture of the *output* from this configuration, instead of just the input of the dialog.

Answer (score 11):

Just type in the watch expression `PAnsiChar(buffPtr)^,16` or `PByte(buffPtr)^,16` if you want the ordinal/byte values.

The trick here is to add the number of pattern repeat after a comma, like `,16`.

It is IMHO more convenient than changing the Watch Properties, and it works with the F7 evaluation command of the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Did you set the watch do dump a region of memory? For some structures that helps.

If you can recompile your application, then define this:

```
type
  T16Values = array[0..15] of Byte;
  P16Values = ^T16Values;
```

Then cast your pointer into a `P16Values`, and view that.

If it is another data type than `Byte`, change the above code accordingly.

Comment: IMHO you don't need that, since the debugger handle custom repetition directly.

Comment: Sometimes it is more convenient to do this at code time, as saving debugger settings requires you to save the whole .DSK, which often results in pain.

Comment: ... or just add ,16 to the expression. No need to change the settings. ;)